# Unable to send email in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have configuration at delopment.rb which looks like this

```
Wiyo::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Don't care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = true

  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true 

  #config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  #config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = { :address => "localhost", :port => 1025 }

  #config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    #:host => "localhost:3000"
  #}


  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port => 587,
    :domain => 'gmail',
    :user_name => "atomambition@gmail.com",
    :password => "********",
    :authentication => 'plain',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
end
```

In Booking Mailer controller, I have

```
class BookingMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  layout 'email'

  default from: "atomambition@gmail.com"

  def test_email
    mail(to: 'avashpdl@yahoo.com', subject: "test email from Avash Poudel")
  end
end
```

I have called to test_email from another controller like

```
def about
  BookingMailer.test_email.deliver
  render:"about"
end
```

I am stuck. How to send email. How to show message if email are successfully sent?

Comment: What error do you get? Please check logs.

Comment: There is no errors visible in website but, in log folder (development.txt), There are below information and then right after it log has all html coding from my email template

Comment: From: atomambition@gmail.com
To: avashpdl@yahoo.com
Message-ID: <52a7fdf8d07_96c3d9a1d814440@user-PC.mail>
Subject: test email from Avash Poudel
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
 boundary="--==_mimepart_52a7fdf7f1c7e_96c3d9a1d814398";
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


----==_mimepart_52a7fdf7f1c7e_96c3d9a1d814398
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Comment: ----==_mimepart_52a7fce3cb803_96cc5485814093
Content-Type: image/png;
 charset=UTF-8;
 filename=wiyo-loog.png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment;
 filename=wiyo-loog.png
Content-ID: <52a7fce3c1fa9_96cc54858139c7@user-PC.mail>

iVBORwo=

----==_mimepart_52a7fce3cb803_96cc5485814093--

Comment: I am testing this on my local server

Comment: Try to log in to your account(atomambition@gmail.com) and make sure you are able to go to your inbox. Then try again sending mail from your code

Comment: Have you authenticated your app with Gmail?

Comment: I have solved this problem by going to  http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha. It fixed myproblem.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing "default_url_options", Have a look to below configuration.

Setting up Mailer is pretty straight froward. Below are the steps you need to flow:

**Create the Mailer**

$ rails generate mailer UserMailer

**Edit the Mailer**

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: 'from@example.com'

  def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

**Environment configuration**

Make sure to do below configuration as per Env.

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.default :charset => "utf-8"

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  :enable_starttls_auto => true,
  :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
  :port => 587,
  :domain => "gmail.com",
  :authentication => :login,
  :user_name => 'xxxxxx@gmail.com',
  :password => 'xxxxxxxxxx',
}
```